# Nested expanding div tag creating scrollbars in Opera - I don't want that

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with an expanding div tag that is nested within another div tag. In IE the expanding div tag expands outside the outer div tag when needed. However, in Chrome, when the inner div tag expands, it causes the outer div tag to get scroll bars. I would like the behavior to be the same as in IE - no scroll bars appear and the content overlaps the body content of the page (after all it is just the shopping cart widget).

Here is the code in my html page.

```
<div id="mastheadcontainer"><!-- Begin mastheadontainer -->
<div id="masthead"><!-- Begin Masthead -->
    <div id="mastheadcontent">
        <div id="googlecart-widget" style="float:right;"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End Masthead -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#mastheadcontainer {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #dcb;
border-bottom:10px solid #0066CC;
/*margin-bottom:20px;*/}


#masthead {
text-align: right;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: auto;}


#mastheadcontent{
width:956px;
height:122px;
margin:0 auto;
/*background-image:url('../images/bk-masthead.jpg');*/
/*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
background-color:#dcb;}
```

Any recommendations so that the inner div tag expands similar to the behavior in IE when viewed in chrome?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your are talking about vertical scrolling and that the content inside your #mastheadcontent id is making a scroll bar appear when it exceeds 122 pixels.

I am not sure exactly what you want the end result will look like but here is what I suggest depending on what you are looking for:

- Remove the height of the container so that the div will expand to fit the content inside of it. Note that since you are using a floated inside the container you will have to clear the container using a number of methods, one of them is using the property "overflow: auto;" on the #mastheadcontent. If you are not familiar with clearing floats I suggest you look at the multitude of guides on the web to help you understand the concept.
- Or you want the content to expand past the boundaries but not expand the container itself, in that case you might want to use the property "overflow: visible;".

In any case you might want to play with the overflow property to get a solution to your problem, there is plenty of information on the web that should clear things up for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I would like the content to expand past the boundary but not expand the container. I have changed the overflow property to visible, but that still isn't working in Chrome. IE has no problem as the code is now. I haven't checked in Firefox though. In my instance, when I the inner div expands, it causes both vertical and horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: I solved my own problem. I basically had a main div tag, and within that, I had a div tag that contained multiple div tags for header content. Below that I had a body div tag that contained multiple div tags for the body content. To get a specific div tag in the header o expand over the top of the body div tags, I had to set my OVERFLOW:VISIBLE for all head div tags. It worked so now I'm not getting scrollbars in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. Here is the current div structure of my site:

```
<div id="main>
<div id="mastheadcontainer"><!-- Begin mastheadontainer -->
<div id="masthead"><!-- Begin Masthead -->
<div id="mastheadcontent">
<div id="googlecart-widget" style="float:right;"></div>
</div>
</div><!-- End Masthead -->   
<div id="bodydiv">       
</div><!-- End bodydiv -->
</div><!-- End main -->
```

To get the googlecart-widget to expand over the top of the content in the bodydiv element in Chrome, I had to add overflow:visible to all div elements in the mastheadcontainer and to the mastheadcontainer element. My new HTML div structure looks like this:

```
<div id="main>
<div id="mastheadcontainer" style="overflow:visible;"><!-- Begin mastheadontainer -->
<div id="masthead" style="overflow:visible;"><!-- Begin Masthead -->
<div id="mastheadcontent" style="overflow:visible;">
<div id="googlecart-widget" style="float:right; overflow:visible;"></div>
</div>
</div><!-- End Masthead -->   
<div id="bodydiv">       
</div><!-- End bodydiv -->
</div><!-- End main -->
```

This might be a bit of overkill setting the overflow property for all elements, but it worked.